# File with irregular patterns AWK

Tags: perl, awk

I have a file with such structure:

file1

```
>ENSGALG00000000011|ENSGALT00000000012|57|1123|1125
cttttccactttgctctcatcCTGCTATTGGATTTgagatgcatgtcTGTTAATATTGTA
AGATTGGTGGTACATGACTGTCCTCTTTGGGATATATTTGACAGTGACTGGTATACTTCT
CGCAGTCTCATTGGAGGAGCTGATATTATTGTGATTaaatactctgtcaatGACAAGACT
>ENSGALG00000000012|ENSGALT00000000013|57|1145|1155
cttttccactttgctctcatcCTGCTATTGGATTTgagatgcatgtcTGTTAATATTGTA
GCCAATCACATTAGAAATCCTGTTTTTACTGAATATCAAGCCTGCGTGTTTGGAAATGTC
AGATTGGTGGTACATGACTGTCCTCTTTGGGATATATTTGACAGTGACTGGTATACTTCT
CGCAGTCTCATTGGAGGAGCTGATATTATTGTGATTaaatactctgtcaatGACAAGACT
>ENSGALG00000000015|ENSGALT00000000014|57|1144|1155
GCCAATCACATTAGAAATCCTGTTTTTACTGAATATCAAGCCTGCGTGTTTGGAAATGTC
AGATTGGTGGTACATGACTGTCCTCTTTGGGATATATTTGACAGTGACTGGTATACTTCT
CGCAGTCTCATTGGAGGAGCTGATATTATTGTGATTaaatactctgtcaatGACAAGACT
```

I want to use another file to extract the ones that have a specific idea in the first part, that is to use this file:

file2
Code:

```
ENSGALG00000000011
ENSGALG00000000015
```

To want the final output to be like this:

```
>ENSGALG00000000011|ENSGALT00000000012|57|1123|1125
cttttccactttgctctcatcCTGCTATTGGATTTgagatgcatgtcTGTTAATATTGTA
AGATTGGTGGTACATGACTGTCCTCTTTGGGATATATTTGACAGTGACTGGTATACTTCT
CGCAGTCTCATTGGAGGAGCTGATATTATTGTGATTaaatactctgtcaatGACAAGACT
>ENSGALG00000000015|ENSGALT00000000014|57|1144|1155
GCCAATCACATTAGAAATCCTGTTTTTACTGAATATCAAGCCTGCGTGTTTGGAAATGTC
AGATTGGTGGTACATGACTGTCCTCTTTGGGATATATTTGACAGTGACTGGTATACTTCT
CGCAGTCTCATTGGAGGAGCTGATATTATTGTGATTaaatactctgtcaatGACAAGACT
```

I know this code:

```
awk -F"|" 'FNR==NR{A[">"$1];next}($1 in A){print;getline;print}' file2 file1
```

but the problem is that it only gives me the first line of the content of each of the headers. Apparently, this happens because AWK searches for similar pattern, but I only know AWK, I was wondering whether there is any other way to get the output I need.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.
Cheers,

Comment: So you need a multi-line regex that captures something like `/>ENSGALG00000000011[^>]*/`, correct?

Answer (score 1):

It is frowned upon to post requests for code where you have made little or no effort to solve the problem yourself; however I am too tired to press the point. This Perl program will do as you ask.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %wanted;

{
  open my $fh, '<', 'file2.txt' or die $!;
  while (<$fh>) {
    my ($key) = /(\S*)/;
    $wanted{$key} = 1 if $key;
  }
}

{
  open my $fh, '<', 'file1.txt' or die $!;
  local $/ = '>';
  while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my ($key) = /(\w*)/;
    print ">$_" if $key and $wanted{$key};
  }
}
```

**output**

```
>ENSGALG00000000011|ENSGALT00000000012|57|1123|1125
cttttccactttgctctcatcCTGCTATTGGATTTgagatgcatgtcTGTTAATATTGTA
AGATTGGTGGTACATGACTGTCCTCTTTGGGATATATTTGACAGTGACTGGTATACTTCT
CGCAGTCTCATTGGAGGAGCTGATATTATTGTGATTaaatactctgtcaatGACAAGACT
>ENSGALG00000000015|ENSGALT00000000014|57|1144|1155
GCCAATCACATTAGAAATCCTGTTTTTACTGAATATCAAGCCTGCGTGTTTGGAAATGTC
AGATTGGTGGTACATGACTGTCCTCTTTGGGATATATTTGACAGTGACTGGTATACTTCT
CGCAGTCTCATTGGAGGAGCTGATATTATTGTGATTaaatactctgtcaatGACAAGACT
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sure, I know this is a very wrong thing to do that but that's what happens when you must do a lot in short amount of time and you know so little. Please accept my apologies.

Comment: @user3083423 - just have in mind that you won't get very far if you keep doing it. If your job description expects you to be able to process large bodies of textual data, learn Perl.

Comment: I don't suppose the downvoter is brave enough to explain himself?

Answer (score 1):

Awk:

```
awk -F '|' 'NR==FNR {code[">" $1]=1; next} /^>/ {p = ($1 in code)} p' file2 file1
```

```
>ENSGALG00000000011|ENSGALT00000000012|57|1123|1125
cttttccactttgctctcatcCTGCTATTGGATTTgagatgcatgtcTGTTAATATTGTA
AGATTGGTGGTACATGACTGTCCTCTTTGGGATATATTTGACAGTGACTGGTATACTTCT
CGCAGTCTCATTGGAGGAGCTGATATTATTGTGATTaaatactctgtcaatGACAAGACT
>ENSGALG00000000015|ENSGALT00000000014|57|1144|1155
GCCAATCACATTAGAAATCCTGTTTTTACTGAATATCAAGCCTGCGTGTTTGGAAATGTC
AGATTGGTGGTACATGACTGTCCTCTTTGGGATATATTTGACAGTGACTGGTATACTTCT
CGCAGTCTCATTGGAGGAGCTGATATTATTGTGATTaaatactctgtcaatGACAAGACT
```

First, reads the `file2` codes. Then, for any line starting with `>`, sets a boolean variable to true if the first value is a "valid" code.

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} NF {for (i in a) if (i~$0) print ">"$0} ' RS=">" file2 file1
>ENSGALG00000000011|ENSGALT00000000012|57|1123|1125
cttttccactttgctctcatcCTGCTATTGGATTTgagatgcatgtcTGTTAATATTGTA
AGATTGGTGGTACATGACTGTCCTCTTTGGGATATATTTGACAGTGACTGGTATACTTCT
CGCAGTCTCATTGGAGGAGCTGATATTATTGTGATTaaatactctgtcaatGACAAGACT

>ENSGALG00000000015|ENSGALT00000000014|57|1144|1155
GCCAATCACATTAGAAATCCTGTTTTTACTGAATATCAAGCCTGCGTGTTTGGAAATGTC
AGATTGGTGGTACATGACTGTCCTCTTTGGGATATATTTGACAGTGACTGGTATACTTCT
CGCAGTCTCATTGGAGGAGCTGATATTATTGTGATTaaatactctgtcaatGACAAGACT
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a FASTA file format and there is a really simple way to read and write it:

```
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my $file         = shift; # get the file name, somehow
my $seqio_object = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => $file);
my $seq_object   = $seqio_object->next_seq;
```

http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/HOWTO:SeqIO

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, which asked specifically how to select sequences from the FASTA file according to the IDs in another file. Reading the file is simple, and there is no need for the module.

Comment: @Borodin I'm not sure the reinventing existing working heavily used by bio community module is a good idea. Reading FASTA is simple and fast. You don't need an AWK here at all. You are not going to save anything at all using AWK.